# Changing Excel CSV column limit

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

When I import tilde-delimited text files, Excel 365 is truncating them at 50 columns, with the remaining columns silently discarded. I can't find a setting that controls this limit. How can I import delimited files with more than 50 columns?

Here's a single line from the file (425 columns):

> Schema_InvcHead~RptLanguageID~AGAuthorizationCode~AGAuthorizationDate~AGDocConcept~AGDocumentLetter~AGInvoicingPoint~AGLegalNumber~AGPrintingControlType~AGUseGoodDefaultMark~ApplyDate~ARLOCID~AutoPrintReady~BillingDate~BillingNumber~BillToInvoiceAddress~BlockedFinChrg~BlockedFinChrgReason~BlockedRemLetters~BlockedRemLettersReason~BranchID~ChangeDate~ChangedBy~ChangeTime~CHISRCodeLine~CMReason~CMType~CNConfirmDate~CNTaxInvoiceType~CollectionsCust~Company~Consolidated~ContractDate~ContractRef~CopyLatestInvoice~CorrectionInv~CounterARForm~CreditMemo~CurrRateDate~CustAgentName~CustAgentTaxRegNo~CustNum~CycleCode~CycleInactive~DebitNote~Deferred~DepositAmt~DepositCredit~DepUnallocatedAmt~DNComments~DNCustNbr~DocDepApplied~DocDepositAmt~DocDepositCredit~DocDepUnallocatedAmt~DocInvoiceAmt~DocMaxValueAmt~DocPECharges~DocPECommissions~DocPEDetTaxAmt~DocPEDischargeAmt~DocPEInterest~DocPENoPayPenalty~DocRecurBalance~DocRounding~DocumentPrinted~DocWithholdAmt~DueDate~Duration~EDIReady~EInvException~EInvoice~EInvRefNum~EInvStatus~EInvTimestamp~EInvUpdatedBy~EndDate~Excluded~ExportDocDate~ExportDocRefNum~ExportReportNo~ExportType~FiscalCalendarID~FiscalYearSuffix~GUIDateOfExport~GUIDeductCode~GUIExportBillNumber~GUIExportBillType~GUIExportMark~GUIExportType~GUIFormatCode~GUITaxTypeCode~HeadNum~HoldInvoice~INExportProcedure~InPrice~INShippingPortCode~InstanceNum~INTaxTransactionID~InvInCollections~InvoiceAmt~InvoiceComment~InvoiceDate~InvoiceNum~InvoiceNumList~InvoiceRef~InvoiceType~IsAddedToGTI~IsRecurring~LastChrgCalcDate~LastDate~LegalNumber~LockTaxRate~MainSite~MaxValueAmt~MXAccountNumber~MXApprovalNum~MXApprovalYear~MXCancellationMode~MXCancelledDate~MXCBB~MXCertificate~MXCertificateSN~MXCertifiedTimestamp~MXConfirmationCode~MXDigitalSeal~MXDomesticTransfer~MXExportCertOrigin~MXExportCertOriginNum~MXExportConfNum~MXExportCustDocCode~MXExportOperationType~MXExternalCode~MXFiscalFolio~MXFolio~MXIncoterm~MXInvoiceRelationType~MXMovingReason~MXMovingReasonFlag~MXNumRegIdTrib~MXOriginalAmount~MXOriginalDate~MXOriginalFolio~MXOriginalSeries~MXOriginalString~MXOriginalStringTFD~MXPaidAs~MXPartPmt~MXPaymentName~MXPaymentNum~MXPostedTimeStamp~MXPurchaseType~MXResidenCountryNum~MXSATCertificateSN~MXSATSeal~MXSerie~MXTaxRcptType~MXTaxRegime~MXTotalPayments~OrdExchangeRate~OrigDueDate~OurBank~OurSupplierCode~Overpaid~OverrideEndDate~OvrDefTaxDate~PayDiscDays~PayDiscPartPay~PayDiscPer~PBProjectID~PEAPPayNum~PEBankNumber~PEBOEIsMultiGen~PEBOEPosted~PEBOEStatus~PECharges~PECommissions~PEDebitNote~PEDebitNoteReasonCode~PEDetTaxAmt~PEDetTaxCurrencyCode~PEDischargeAmt~PEDischargeDate~PEGuaranteeAddress1~PEGuaranteeAddress2~PEGuaranteeAddress3~PEGuaranteeCity~PEGuaranteeCountry~PEGuaranteeName~PEGuaranteePhoneNum~PEGuaranteeState~PEGuaranteeTaxID~PEGuaranteeZip~PEInterest~PENoPayPenalty~PEReasonCode~PEReasonDesc~PERefDocID~PESUNATDepAmt~PESUNATDepDate~PESUNATDepNum~PIPayment~Plant~PMUID~PONum~PostedRecog~RateGrpCode~ReadyToBill~ReadyToCalc~RealEstateNo~RecalcBeforePost~RecurBalance~RecurringState~RecurSource~RefCancelled~RefCancelledBy~ReversalDocAmount~RevisionDate~RevisionNum~Rounding~Rpt1DepGainLoss~Rpt1DepositAmt~Rpt1DepUnallocatedAmt~Rpt1MaxValueAmt~Rpt1PECharges~Rpt1PECommissions~Rpt1PEDischargeAmt~Rpt1PEInterest~Rpt1PENoPayPenalty~Rpt1RecurBalance~Rpt1WithholdAmt~Rpt2DepGainLoss~Rpt2DepositAmt~Rpt2DepUnallocatedAmt~Rpt2MaxValueAmt~Rpt2PECharges~Rpt2PECommissions~Rpt2PEDischargeAmt~Rpt2PEInterest~Rpt2PENoPayPenalty~Rpt2RecurBalance~Rpt2WithholdAmt~Rpt3DepGainLoss~Rpt3DepositAmt~Rpt3DepUnallocatedAmt~Rpt3MaxValueAmt~Rpt3PECharges~Rpt3PECommissions~Rpt3PEDischargeAmt~Rpt3PEInterest~Rpt3PENoPayPenalty~Rpt3RecurBalance~Rpt3WithholdAmt~SEBankRef~ServiceInvoice~ShipDate~SiteCode~SoldToCustNum~SoldToInvoiceAddress~SummarizationDate~SysRevID~SysRowID~TaxPoint~TaxRateDate~TaxRateGrpCode~TaxRegionCode~THIsImmatAdjustment~TotFinChrg~TranDocTypeID~TWDeclarePeriod~TWDeclareYear~TWGenerationType~TWGUIExportDocumentName~TWGUIExportRemarks~TWGUIExportVerification~TWGUIGroup~TWGUIRegNumBuyer~TWGUIRegNumSeller~TWPeriodPrefix~UseAltBillTo~UseAltBillToID~WithholdAmt~WithTaxConfirm~XRefContractDate~XRefContractNum~Division_c~Calc_BillToAddressList~Calc_BottomAddress~Calc_BTAddressList~Calc_CHBankAcctIBANCode~Calc_CHBankAcctISRPartyID~Calc_CompanyAddressList~Calc_ConReference~Calc_ConStartDate~Calc_CounterARForm~Calc_CreditMemo~Calc_CurrDesc~Calc_CurrDocDecimalsGeneral~Calc_CurrDocDecimalsPrice~Calc_CurrDocDesc~Calc_CurSymbol~Calc_CustContactName~Calc_CustEMailAddress~Calc_CustFax~Calc_CustID~Calc_CustPartOpts~Calc_CustPhone~Calc_CustResaleID~Calc_DiscountTotal~Calc_DocDspTaxAmt~Calc_DocInvoiceAmt~Calc_DropShipPackSlip~Calc_DteOrdrd~Calc_ExtPriceTotal~Calc_fFOB~Calc_GuiFormatCodeDesc~Calc_InvoiceRefDate~Calc_InvoiceRefLegalNumber~Calc_InvSubTotal~Calc_InvSuffix~Calc_IsBaseCurr~Calc_IsDraftCopy~Calc_MscTotal~Calc_MtlTotal~Calc_MulPackNum~Calc_mulponum~Calc_MulShipDate~Calc_MulShipTo~Calc_MulShipVia~Calc_MulShpCon~Calc_MultSoldTo~Calc_MultTaxID~Calc_MXApprovalNumber~Calc_MXApprovalYear~Calc_MXCBB~Calc_MXCertificateSN~Calc_MXCertifiedTimeStamp~Calc_MXDigitalSeal~Calc_MXExpeditionAddress~Calc_MXFiscalFolio~Calc_MXFolio~Calc_MXOrigFiscalFolio~Calc_MXOrigFiscalFolioAmount~Calc_MXOrigFiscalFolioDate~Calc_MXOrigFiscalFolioSeries~Calc_MXOriginalString1~Calc_MXOriginalString10~Calc_MXOriginalString2~Calc_MXOriginalString3~Calc_MXOriginalString4~Calc_MXOriginalString5~Calc_MXOriginalString6~Calc_MXOriginalString7~Calc_MXOriginalString8~Calc_MXOriginalString9~Calc_MXOriginalStringTFD~Calc_MXPaidAs~Calc_MXPaymentAccountNum~Calc_MXPaymentMethod~Calc_MXPaymentNum~Calc_MXSATCertificateSN~Calc_MXSATSeal~Calc_MXSerie~Calc_MXTaxRegime~Calc_MXTotalPayments~Calc_NumRecordPerPage~Calc_NumTotalParts~Calc_PackNum~Calc_PELegalText~Calc_PeriodEndDate~Calc_PPAllowPcnt~Calc_PrintBottomAddress~Calc_RefInvAmt~Calc_RefInvNum~Calc_RevisionDate~Calc_RevisionNum~Calc_RUBTLegalName~Calc_RUCorrToInvDate~Calc_RUCorrToInvLegalNumber~Calc_RUCorrToInvRevDate~Calc_RUCorrToInvRevNum~Calc_RULessDeposits~Calc_RusNumber~Calc_SalesPerson~Calc_SalesTerms~Calc_SEBankRef~Calc_ShipDate~Calc_ShipTo~Calc_ShipToAddressList~Calc_ShipToContactName~Calc_ShipVia~Calc_ShpConNum~Calc_SoldToAddressList~Calc_SubTotal~Calc_TaxMethod~Calc_TotalMiscChrg~Calc_vDocPayAmounts~Calc_VoucherString~Calc_Voucher-String~Calc_vPayAmounts~Calc_vPayDates~CurrencyCode_CurrDesc~CurrencyCode_CurrName~CurrencyCode_CurrSymbol~CurrencyCode_DocumentDesc~Customer_BTName~Customer_CustID~Customer_Name~Customer_TradingPartnerName~FOB_DeliveryTerms~FOB_Description~Plant_Address1~Plant_Address2~Plant_Address3~Plant_City~Plant_Company~Plant_CountryNum~Plant_Name~RMANum_RMADate~RMANum_RMANum~RMANum_ShipToNum~RMANum_XRefRMANumber~TermsCode_Description~TermsCode_NumberOfPayments~TermsCode_TermsCode~

If I put this line in a file by itself and try to import it into Excel, the option to select the delimiter disappears (not disabled, it's gone from the UI completely) and it's treated as a single column. OO Calc imports the single line or the complete file with no issue.

Comment: Are you sure they're being truncated and it's not blank columns being treated as one column? Check to make sure you don't have **'Treat consecutive delimiters as one'** checked in the **Text Import Wizard**.

Comment: Office 365, is hardly the cause, but I'm not using it so can't test. Or, were you able to import the file in other Excel versions? Anyway in earlier offices I can not reproduce the problem (tested with a hundred column file).

Comment: @TomBrunberg It imports correctly in OpenOffice Calc.

Comment: @angelofdev I used Data > From Text/CSV. There is no such option there.

Comment: @angelofdev Oddly enough, if I search the help for "text import wizard", the information appears to be for an older version of Excel.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include a couple of lines of a tilde-delimited text file? (Open the file in a text editor and copy-paste the lines.)

Comment: check this limk,, https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/contacts/how-many-columns-can-i-include-when-importing-a-csv-file.

Comment: @robinCTS Added a line.

Comment: @RajeshS The limit seems to have been changed from 1000 to 50.

Comment: @TKK That link is for CSV files. I don't think that limit applies for Tilda-delimited files. Anyways, all I have here is Excel 2007, and that line works just fine with it.

Comment: @robinCTS In 365, the Text/CSV import normally has an option that lets you specify other delimiters. (Which disappeared when I tried to import a single line.) I'm thinking 365 is a major regression from earlier versions.

Comment: I pasted your sample line into a new .txt file and opened it in Excel 365 ProPlus (version 1805, build 9330.2124), after going through the Text-To-Columns wizards it parsed it correctly, putting TermsCode_TermsCode in column PI (i.e. #425). Instead of loading via Data > From Text/CSV, can you load by File > Open > Selecting your file (you may need to change the filter to All Files (*.*), and then in the Text Import Wizard selected Delimited > Delimited: Other (enter "~") > Finish ?

Comment: @mlhDev File > Open > Browse - clicking the Browse icon is crucial, as there is no file type option if you simply browse under This PC. (Utterly insane UX...) Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a little bit of testing it seems the Data > From Text/CSV doesn't prompt you to parse the file and split it out into columns (without another manual step).

I've tested this method and it works with Excel 365 (version 1805; thanks for the note on the Browse button):

1. In Excel, navigate to File > Open
2. Select Browse so the file selection dialog pops up
3. Change the File Type drop down from All Excel Files to "All Files (*.*)"
4. Navigate to and select your tilde-delimited file

At this point the Text Import Wizard should display

5. In the Original Data Type section ensure Delimited is selected and click Next
6. In the delimiters section uncheck Tab and check Other; type ~ into the box next to Other, then click Next

Other comments mentioned the 'Treat consecutive delimiters as one' option, it is found on this screen. Leave it unchecked but if you don't get the results you are expecting, try again with this checked

7. The 3rd and last step of the Text Import Wizard gives you a preview of the parsed data and lets you change columns' data types. Make any changes you'd like then click Finish
8. You should see your data in an Excel worksheet as you'd expect with all the columns you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this short VBA macro:

```
Sub tildaReader()
    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Close #1
   Open FilesToOpen For Input As #1

   j = 1
   Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, TextLine
        arr = Split(TextLine, "~")
        Cells(j, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
        j = j + 1
   Loop

   Close #1
End Sub
```

typical file:

[image]

result:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

[image]

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the macro from the Excel window:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Everything MS is completely alien to me. Can you explain where that code snippet would go?

Comment: @TKK  See my **EDIT#1**